# Why isn't the following a Linear Map?

Tags: linear-algebra

Please explain why this isn't a linear map.

$$\varphi \colon \mathbb{Q}[x] \to \mathbb{Q}[t],\qquad ax^2 + bx +c \mapsto 2at^2 + 3t + b$$

Comment: What's $\varphi(0)$?

Comment: What is the definition of a linear map?  Why doesn't $\varphi$ fit that definition?

Comment: Without considering linearity questions, this is actually not a well-defined map: what is $\varphi(x^3)$?

Comment: That's what the solution I was given says! "Not a map" and the counter example is the one you stated (emeu). But why isn't it a map? Why can't you put x^3 into the map?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**

If $a=b=c=0$ then the polynomial $ax^2+bx+c=0$.
What's $\varphi(0)$?

Or else: $$\text{does}\;\varphi(2)=2\varphi(1)?$$

Comment: φ(0)=0? Is that right? If so, what's wrong with that?

Comment: No as I explained we find the polynomial $0$ by taking $a=b=c=0$ and then $\varphi(0)=2\times0\times t^2+2t+0=2t\ne0$ hence $\varphi$ isn't linear.

Comment: But why isn't $φ$ a map?

Comment: No $\varphi$ is a map but it isn't linear so we say it isn't linear map.

Comment: $\inf(-1)\to-\infty$